# Titanium - How do I prevent the textField losing focus when pressing return

Tags: javascript, ios, titanium, appcelerator

I'm using the titanium API to write an iOS app in javascript. The problem I ran into is that when I have a text field and I click on it to type in, I want to be able to press the return key without blurring the focus on the text field thus minimising the keyboard. I want to be able to press return and keep the keyboard open. Does anyone have a suggestion? (Immediately re-focussing the text field on the 'return' event is ugly and not at all what I was hoping for)

Here's a brief bit of code to recreate this issue:

```
    var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({backgroundColor: 'white'});

    var textBox = Ti.UI.createTextField({
      borderStyle: Ti.UI.INPUT_BORDERSTYLE_ROUNDED,
      width: 240, height: 30,
      top: 30, left: 10
    });

    textBox.addEventListener('return', someFunction());

    win.add(textBox);
    win.open();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the textArea instead of textBox but style it the same. Then handle the behaviour you want when the user presses the return key.

Comment: Thanks for the solution but I'm still finding it has exactly the same behaviour. I would have thought this was configurable through the textField/textArea's properties but I can't find anything in the documentation.

Comment: The whole point of a textArea is you can add multiple lines.. This is the default behaviour. Try removing the 'return' event. To prove this to yourself create a new blank project and just add a text area to the screen, just to make sure nothing else you're doing is getting in the way. My textAreas do not blur on the return key.